# Javascript assigned CSS background-image issue

Tags: javascript, css, background-image

I wrote this code that gives for each class .hpCarousel the relating background image.

The image names being: 0bg.jpg, 1jpg.bg, 2bg.jpg, etc...

```
for (i=0; i < 8; i++) {
$('.hpCarousel:eq('+i+')').css('background-image', 'url(wp-content/themes/blankslate/assets/carousel/'+i+'bg.jpg');
}
```

It works fine in Firefox. The classes have a style with their correct background-image assigned.

[image]

It does not work in Chrome OSX&WIN /Safari OSX/ IE. The .hpCarousel class divs have no style.

[image]

I thought at first it was something to do with Chrome's background refresh bug. But finding it on other browsers has made me think otherwise.

Am I clearly doing something wrong?

**These classes are hidden on load. Does that make any difference? Then they fade in and out after one another to produce a carousel**

Comment: Have you set height,width (possibly to 100%)? Also you might try using background instead of background-image

Comment: Yes, height and width are set.
Changing to 'background' instead of 'background-image' does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have errors in FireBug?
You could use another (more general) selector in the loop:

```
$('.hpCarousel:nth-child(' + i + ')')
```

Also the `$.each` iterator is a more convenient way to iterate through your backgrounds.

```
$('.hpCarousel').each(function(index) {
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(wp-content/themes/blankslate/assets/carousel/'+index+'bg.jpg');
});
```

Comment: I did not know the usage of index in .each, but this is clearly the right way to go. Thanks